# Training Mask RCNN but always get 0 positive bounding boxes from all proposals?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, faster-rcnn

I've just implemented a Mask RCNN in Pytorch from scratch and here is the code: https://github.com/arthurhero/Mask_R-CNN_Pytorch/blob/master/masker_ops.py

I have only one GTX1080 and one Quadro6000 on two separate machines, so I can only train with 2 imgs per iteration. My questions is, how long does it usually take for Mask RCNN to converge? And how can I tell whether it's on the right track or not?

Right now I'm only training the RPN head (so it's the first of the four "pragmatic steps"). After one night's training, this model still gives me a lot of "0 positive bboxes" notice, i.e., when it assigns labels to each bbox for a img, all of them are negative (does not have large enough iou with a ground-truth bbox). And it seems the number of "0 positive bboxes" notice did not decrease as the training goes at all.

I've thought of several reasons.

1. Right now, I will skip the whole batch if one of the img has "0 positive bboxes", just because it will make the tensor shape strange for later computations. Is this how people usually deal with this kind of situation? Is it bringing too much inefficiency to training?
2. The learning rate might be too big? I'm currently using 0.02 from the paper. But since my batch size is only 2, is this learning rate too huge?
3. I have a bit doubt in the way the offsets are applied to the anchors... Currently, the RPN head returns dy,dx,logh,logw relative to the anchor box. And the code for applying these offsets to anchor box is like this:

   `center_y = center_y + (dy*height)
    center_x = center_x + (dx*width)
    height = height * torch.exp(dh)
    width = width * torch.exp(dw)`

   The resulting bbox might be well out of the boundary of the original anchor (if dy and dx are large). But when this bbox is assigned "negative", the class label at the center of the original anchor will receive punishment if the label is positive. This does not look fair to me...... Am I having a misunderstanding here? Or does it just not matter? Should we put some hard constraint on those offsets so the resulting bbox cannot go too far away from the anchor?
4. Too many for loops. This is a problem for the ROIAlign layer and Proposal filter layer. Since each img might have different numbers of filtered proposals, and also just because it's hard to manipulate a 5D tensor... I usually just split the batch of bboxes or proposals along the batch axis, and use a for loop to deal with the set of proposals for one img at a time. But from my limited knowledge of OS, GPU's seem to be bad at doing serial work. Are those for loops dragging the speed of training? And is there a better way to implement those computations on 5d tensors without a for loop?
5. Too few GPU's. The fundamental question: is it even possible to train a Mask RCNN on only one GPU? If not... what are the recommendations for a object masker with cheaper cost? I heard YOLO is also very computationally expensive...

Many, many thanks!!

-Z